# Tooltip min-height works but not min-width

Tags: html, css

I have a tooltip from this page:

http://www.cssportal.com/css-tooltip-generator/

I adapted it to apply to a input element:

```
<div class="tooltip">
     <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre/s" name="dp_nombre">
     <span>Nombre completo asd as dasd as dasd</span>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
}
.tooltip span {
    position: absolute;
    width: 120px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: #327FBA;
    min-height: 32px;
    line-height: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    visibility: hidden;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.tooltip span:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 100%;
    margin-top: -8px;
    width: 0; height: 0;
    border-right: 8px solid #327FBA;
    border-top: 8px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
}
.tooltip:hover span {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 0.9;
    left: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -16px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

The problem is that if the text is longer than the width, it makes a line break, and it is not contained by the tooltip background.

In `.tooltip span {}` I've replaced `width:` with `min-width:` and it didn't work. Tried with `width: auto` also but the tooltip becomes narrower.

However, replacing `height` with `min-height` DID make the tooltip background contain the text vertically.

**How can I make the tooltip contain the text up to, say 300px? (using max-width) Then line break and keep containing it vertically.**

Thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/hrfz442d/

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `max-width` but add `display:table`

```
.tooltip span {
    position: absolute;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: #327FBA;
    min-height: 32px;
    line-height: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    visibility: hidden;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: table;
    max-width:150px;
    padding:0 .5em;
}
```

[**Jsfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hrfz442d/6/)

Comment: Thanks, can you make it have a max-width of 150px, THEN line break?

Comment: Thanks Paulie but I don't see it working, I am changing the max-width in your JSFiddle but stills the same. Maybe its Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

Just add this CSS.

```
.tooltip span {
    position: absolute;
    width: 120px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: #327FBA;
    min-height: 32px;
    line-height: 16px; /* change the line-height */
    text-align: center;
    visibility: hidden;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    word-break: break-word;
    display: table;
}
```

After this you can change the line-height accordingly.

Comment: would you be so kind to add a bit of explanation? Consider that this will be used as a reference by users that will read this later

Comment: Also, please test in Firefox, I've tried your solution but it's not working in FF 38